# How to catch exception thrown from observable subscription in test

Tags: angular, jasmine, observable

I'm not sure how to handle exceptions with URL parameters in Angular 6. Right now my service throws an `Error` when the URL id cannot be found. In the actual app I like that the error bubbles up to be caught and logged, but in my jasmine tests that results in a test failure:

```
HeroDetailComponent should navigate to not found page
[object ErrorEvent] thrown
```

I've tried various `try {} catch () {}` blocks and `catchError` pipelines to handle the error in jasmine, but nothing seems to be able to catch this Error after the test expects run.

Demo of the issue: https://angular-observable-catch.stackblitz.io/

Note that on stackblitz the test doesn't fail, but it does locally when run in my application using `ng test`.

In the (main) console note the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Hero 999 not found.
    at HeroService.getHeroById (hero.service.ts:33)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.eval [as project] (hero-detail.component.ts:46)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (switchMap.ts:103)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:104)
    at ReplaySubject.Subject.next (Subject.ts:62)
    at ReplaySubject.nextInfiniteTimeWindow (ReplaySubject.ts:42)
    at ActivatedRouteStub.setParamMap (activated-route-stub.ts:56)
    at UserContext.eval (hero-detail.component.spec.ts:65)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (zone-testing.js:288)
```

Source code for the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-observable-catch?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero%2Fhero-detail.component.spec.ts

How do I catch this error in my jasmine tests so it doesn't cause an Uncaught Error?

---

**Update**

I figured out that this is caused by the [AsyncPipe subscription](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8282e15c2becbe42a49befa07d6407247e8243d8/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L22) which throws any errors the Observable/Promise/etc.

Answer (score 0):

A work around I found for this issue is to replace the AsyncPipe in TestBed with one that won't throw the errors.

test-async-pipe.ts:

```
import { AsyncPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * When the AsyncPipe throws errors Jasmine cannot catch them and causes tests to fail.
 * For tests just log the error and move on.
 * Add this class to the TestBed.configureTestingModule declarations.
 */
@Pipe({name: 'async', pure: false}) // tslint:disable-line:use-pipe-transform-interface
export class TestAsyncPipe extends AsyncPipe {
  transform(obj: any): any {
    const ret = super.transform(obj);
    const handleError = (err: any) => { console.error('AsyncPipe Template Exception', err); };
    // @ts-ignore: patch the Observable error handler to not throw an error in tests.
    this._subscription.destination._error = handleError;
    // What if the subscription is a Promise?
    return ret;
  }
}
```

a-test.spec.ts

```
import { async, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { TestAsyncPipe } from '../testing/test-async-pipe';

import { TestComponent} from './test.component';

describe('TestComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TestAsyncPipe, TestComponent],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
});
```